# PHP exec() does not accept java classpath

Tags: java, php, exception, classpath

When I run command from console, like this, it works:

```
java -cp /root/weka-3-6-11/weka.jar weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove {Parameters come here}
```

But when I run it with PHP, it gives me an error, I think it doesn't use the provided classpath:

```
exec('java -cp /root/weka-3-6-11/weka.jar weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove {Parameters come here}');


[0] => Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Remove
[1] => Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove
[2] =>  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
[3] =>  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[4] =>  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
[5] =>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
[6] =>  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
[7] =>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
[8] => Could not find the main class: weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove. Program will exit.
```

Somewhere I have read that PHP uses its own class path for java, but I cannot get it to work. So far I have tried to execute these lines before the exec command, but still the same exception:

```
echo getcwd() . "\n"; //  /var/www/yugo_api/web
exec("env", $output);
print_r( $output ); // output is below

Array
(
[0] => APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2
[1] => APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
[2] => PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[3] => APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2
[4] => LANG=C
[5] => APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
[6] => APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
[7] => APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2
[8] => PWD=/var/www/yugo_api/web
)

putenv("CLASSPATH=".$cp); // value of $cp is /root/weka-3-6-11/weka.jar
```

Commands run in terminal:

env

```
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=XXX
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
PWD=/var/www/yugo_api
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=XXX
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/root
```

Comment: run `env` from your terminal, and check what the classpath is set to there.

Comment: Thanks for help, I have added the output env gives me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like your apache server user does not have access to the location

```
/root/weka-3-6-11/weka.jar
```

You can verify this by running

```
filesize("/root/weka-3-6-11/weka.jar")
```

from within PHP.

Any program started by `exec` will run as the same user as the apache server user - make sure that you set the permissions on your jar file and its parent directory so that the apache server user (usually user `www-data`) can read it.

Comment: I have thought of permissions before. And I think you are right. filesize() does not output anything, so I think it does not have the rights. Could you help me set them? I'm not so experienced with setting permissions.:) And yes, the user is www-data.

Comment: You could modify permissions, but maybe the best way is to put the file in a location where it can be read? Try creating a directory somewhere `/usr/share/weka` and set run the following `chmod 755 -R /usr/share/weka`